# Could somebody explain me how to make responsive design?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It's been a long time that i have a question. I want to make a responsive website. I use bootstrap and media queries. For example, here is my code:

```
<div class="row-fluid slider">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto">

       <!-- Carousel items -->
       <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active" style="border:1px solid black">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img class="image img-responsive" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/recog/slide1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                     <div class="slider_text"><span>Закінчили складний проект?</span><br />Не забудь подякувати та запросили своїх колег на каву:)</div>
                </div>
          </div>
           <div class="item" style="border:1px solid black">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img class="image" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/recog/slide1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                     <div class="slider_text"><span>Закінчили складний проект?</span><br />Не забудь подякувати та запросили своїх колег на каву:)</div>
                </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item" style="border:1px solid black">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img class="image" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/recog/slide1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                     <div class="slider_text"><span>Закінчили складний проект?</span><br />Не забудь подякувати та запросили своїх колег на каву:)</div>
                </div>
          </div>

       </div>

           <!-- Carousel indicators -->

           <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
           </ol>
       <!-- Carousel nav -->

       <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" 
          data-slide="prev"><img class="image" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/recog/back.png"></a>
       <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" 
          data-slide="next"><img class="image" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/recog/forward.png"></a>
    </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I'm using media queries for every resolutions, for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1920px) and (max-height:1080px){
.slider_text {
    float:left;
    margin-top:0%;
    margin-left:4%;
    margin-top:3%;
}

.image {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    max-width:35%;
    margin-top:3%;
}

.slider {
    height:440px;
    max-height:40%;

}

}

@media only screen and (max-width:1600px) and (max-height:1200px){
.image {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    max-width:40%;
    margin-top:3%;
}
.slider {
    height:440px;
    max-height:35%;

}

}
```

It is a carousel.
For now everything works well but when i try to Zoom-in my desktop on 125% and more or Zoom-out to 50% every block breaks and it is look awful.

I can't understand what is the solution. How to make it all responsive? Please help me. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want test on Responsiveness, zoom-in/out isn't the right way to do it. You should resize your browser window instead.

One way I like to do it is on Chrome, F12 open Dev Tools on the side, and resize the main window. Dev tools tells you the pixels on the top right corner and you can inspect any element you like.

Also, I do not suggest to start learning responsive design by learning Bootstrap first, I recommend you use pure HTML & CSS to design a website template first.

DevTips on YouTube have a great playlist on designing a responsive website from start to finish https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqGj3iMvMa4KQZUkRjfwMmTq_f1fbxerI

Some code from DevTips, https://github.com/DevTips/Responsive-Web-Design-Basics

Comment: I have a PSD tempate and i have to use IE9+ (main require). I have an expirience to make a css but it was tiny elements, blocks and so on. But on i have to make a large project and i don't know how to make it responsive. Do you mean it is better to start to make it with media quaries without bootstrap? Did i write media quaries correctly or it has to be only width there? When i set only width i have a problem with margin in heaight when i make bigger resolution or zoom it.

Comment: @OlegBereziuk yes do keep use Media Queries to make things responsive, the problem with Bootstrap is it's like cheating, beginner just type in a class name and hope everything works. If you design a full website responsive without Bootstrap, you'll be aware of much more things in design. I updated my answer with some simple code from DevTips, you should take a look at it.

Comment: Thank's, i will look it now. One more question: When i write media-quaries, should i write width or height or both? Like when i write for example max-width then something it max-height, it doesn't work and i can't understand why.

Comment: @OlegBereziuk I don't usually use max-height, because usually things will resize themselves according to max-width.

Comment: How do you handle with margin? I mean for example for resolution 1920px margin:10% will look one way and for resolution 1600px it will look anothe way. How can i solve this?